# Explicit degree two Artin L-function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a cubic field, and $\zeta_K(s)$ the Dedekind zeta function. Then from [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2005974?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) one has the factorization

$$\frac{\zeta_K(s)}{\zeta_{\bf Q}(s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a(n)}{n^s}$$

where $a(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)F(n/d)$ and $F(n)$ is the number of distinct ideals of norm $n$ in $K$.

Is there a reference for this statement? I am also interested in the expression of $a(n)$ for higher degree extensions.

In the case when $K$ is degree 3 cyclic, the quotient splits into a product $L(s,\chi)L(s,\chi^{-1})$ where $\chi$ is an associated cubic character of $K$. We can rewrite the resulting Dirichlet series as above with

$$a(n)=\sum_{d|n}\chi(nd^2)$$

so I don't quite see how the above specializes.

Comment: Since $\zeta_K(s) = \sum F(n)/n^s$ and $1/\zeta_{\mathbf Q}(s) = \sum \mu(n)/n^s$, your first question doesn't quite make sense: are you asking for a reference for how to multiply two Dirichlet series?  Try any introductory book on analytic number theory.  Asking for a reference for "this statement" is almost like asking for a special reference on how to multiply two power series.

Comment: Ah. I know how to multiply two Dirichlet series. What I didn't know was this expression for $\zeta_K(s)$ you gave. My original question---I see now it was not precise---was how to see $\mu(d)F(n/d)$ as $\chi(n)\chi^{-1}(n/d)$.

Comment: Do you mean you did not know what happens to the expression for  $\zeta_K(s)$ if you collect terms that are equal?  Also, $\mu(d)F(n/d)$ is *not* $\chi(n)\chi^{-1}(n/d)$: the second expression has absolute value 0 or 1, while the first often has absolute value greater than 1. Two sums being equal does not mean they are termwise equal!

Comment: Oh, the expression for $\zeta_K(s)$ was clear once I saw it (but I had to see it). I was doubtful precisely because of your second statement about absolute values, but of course this is about infinite series as you say. Thanks!